# Remove interpolation Time series plot for missing values

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, plot, time-series

I'm trying to plot a time series data but I have some problems.

I'm using this code:

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
plt.figure('Fig')
plt.plot(data.index,data.Colum,'g', linewidth=2.0,label='Data')
```

And I get this:
[image]

But I dont want the interpolation between missing values!

How can I achieve this?

Comment: So you just want a scatter plot then? I.e. no lines between missing values?

Comment: i guess you either want a scatter plot as @Sam has said already or you want to change your X-axis in the way that it doesn't have gaps - correct?

Answer (score 6):

Since you are using pandas you could do something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

pd.np.random.seed(1234)
idx = pd.date_range(end=datetime.today().date(), periods=10, freq='D')
vals = pd.Series(pd.np.random.randint(1, 10, size=idx.size), index=idx)
vals.iloc[4:8] = pd.np.nan
print vals
```

Here is an example of a column from a DataFrame with `DatetimeIndex`

```
2016-03-29    4.0
2016-03-30    7.0
2016-03-31    6.0
2016-04-01    5.0
2016-04-02    NaN
2016-04-03    NaN
2016-04-04    NaN
2016-04-05    NaN
2016-04-06    9.0
2016-04-07    1.0
Freq: D, dtype: float64
```

To plot it without dates where data is `NaN` you could do something like this:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
ax.plot(range(vals.dropna().size), vals.dropna())
ax.set_xticklabels(vals.dropna().index.date.tolist());
fig.autofmt_xdate()
```

Which should produce a plot like this:

[image]

The trick here is to replace the dates with some range of values that do not trigger matplotlib's internal date processing when you call `.plot` method.

Later, when the plotting is done, replace the ticklabels with actual dates.
Optionally, call `.autofmt_xdate()` to make labels readable.