# How to plot only business hours and weekdays in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, matplotlib, time-series, data-visualization

I have hourly stock data. 
I need a) to format it so that matplotlib ignores weekends and non-business hours and b) an hourly frequency.

The problem: 
Currently, the graph looks crammed and I suspect it is because matplotlib is taking into account 24 hours instead of 8, and 7 days a week instead of business days.

How do I tell pandas to only take into account business hours, M- F?

How I am graphing the data:
I am looping through a list of price data dataframes, graphing each data frame:

```
mm = 0
for ii in df:

    Ddate = ii['Date']
    Pprice = ii['Price']
    d = Ddate.to_list()
    p = Pprice.to_list()

    dates = make_dt(d)
    prices = unstring(p)
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(dates,prices)
    plt.title(stocks[mm])
    plt.grid(True)
    plt.xlabel('Dates')
    plt.ylabel('Prices')
    mm += 1
```

the graph:
[image]

Comment: I dont know if looping is required, since there is no sample data, but pandas offers a business hours offset : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#dateoffset-objects.

Comment: but we are using matplotlib

Comment: Can you post a sample dataframe? Or share the plot data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273472/how-to-skip-empty-dates-weekends-in-a-financial-matplotlib-python-graph

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to skip empty dates (weekends) in a financial Matplotlib Python graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1273472/how-to-skip-empty-dates-weekends-in-a-financial-matplotlib-python-graph)

Answer (score 0):

To fetch business days, you can use below function:

```
df["IsBDay"] = bool(len(pd.bdate_range(df['date'], df['date'])))
```

//Above line should add a new column into the DF as IsBday.
//You can also use Lambda expression to check and have new column for BDay.

```
df['IsBDay'] = df['date'].apply(lambda x: 'True' if bool(len(pd.bdate_range(x, x))) else 'False')
```

Now create a new DF that will have only True IsBday column value and other columns.

```
df[df.IsBday != 'False']
```

Now your DF is ready for ploting.
Hope this helps.